# SQL: Getting Data from Multiple Columns using Where and Or

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I need to select the rows that contain keywords from multiple columns instead of one column such as:

```
"SELECT * From UserTable WHERE Name='" + name + "'" + " OR FullName='" + name + "'""
```

I want to select whichever row from MULTIPLE COLUMNS that contains the variable 'name'. However the above query doesn't work. What are the changes that should be done?

If Name contains the value or if FullName contains the value or even if both contains the value, I would liek to get those rows :) The current query gives me an exception:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FullName'.
```

**I tried this as well for another example:**

```
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conString);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from TheHive WHERE Variable=@variable or Group like @group", cnn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Variable", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "wef";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Group", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "wef" + "%";

            cnn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                OpalData data = new OpalData();
                data.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id"]);
                data.CodeLine = rdr["CodeLine"].ToString();
                data.Variable = rdr["Variable"].ToString();
                data.Group = rdr["Group"].ToString();
                data.Action = rdr["Action"].ToString();
                data.Number = rdr["Number"].ToString();

                knowledge.Add(data);
            }
```

And its Microsoft Azure table being:

[image]

I still get the same error.

Where I'm just trying to find all the rows that has the string 'wef' and expect the output as all the rows since all rows contain 'wef' in at least one of their columns.

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? You can join your tables for example.

Comment: @SonerGönül extremely sorry, I meant MULTIPLE COLUMNS of the same table

Comment: First thing to fix: stop building your SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL. Your current code won't work for names containing apostrophes, and is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @HartCO I edited the question. It returns an exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh dang, thanks for the heads up mate. I will look in to it now :)

Comment: If your string variable `name`  contains a single quote you have that error here. Follow the advice and start to use parameterized queries

Comment: Are You sure Your column names are correct? If I read all the answers given this is latest possible thing. Can we see datatable structure?

Comment: Can you add your table schematic, maybe a couple of records worth of data too?

Comment: I added another example mate. See if you can spot the problem please :)

Comment: @kidshaw I added another example mate. See if you can spot the problem please :)

Comment: just happened to count the number of double inverted commas in your sql statement, and it is 9 - not an even number, somethings wrong there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you have a situation where Name is a first name like Joe and FullName is like Joe Smith and you want to find either a first name of Joe or a FullName that contains Joe. So it should be:

```
"SELECT * From UsersTable WHERE Name='" + name + "' OR FullName like '" + name + "%'";
```

Ok this is working for me:

```
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
    string name = "Joe";

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from t_Users WHERE Name=@name or FullName like @fullname", cnn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fullname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name + "%";

    cnn.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
    }
```

Comment: This still gives me the same exception mate :(